# Include .pem for git pull / push

Tags: git, authentication, amazon-web-services, ssh, pem

I keep a Git server on Amazon EC2, and in order to `push` or `pull` to it I need to run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/pem/Me.pem`. Is there any way to add this `.pem` file to the Git config such that I won't have to run `ssh-add` each time? I'm thinking of a configuration file in a similar vein to `~/.ssh/config` which lets users configure just such an option (`IdentityFile ~/.ssh/pem/Me.pem`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a fit of inspiration just after posting, I added the following to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host someServer
    Hostname 1.2.3.4
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/pem/Me.pem
```

And I simply cloned the Git repo as such:

```
git clone ssh://someServer/opt/git/someRepo.git
```

This has the terrific effect of including the `.pem` file as needed.

Comment: Great solution. The scp-style someServer:/opt/git/someRepo.git URI syntax still works as well for those who prefer it.

Comment: Are the `hostname` and `user` fields required?

Comment: @PaymahnMoghadasian: If you don't add the fields to the `config` file, then you would have to specify them when SSHing in. I suppose that it would work with the `User` field, try it and let us know. But there would be no way (that I can think of) to specify the `Hostname` field, so you will likely have to add that one to the `config` file.